# How to bulk rename objects in ascending order

Tags: scripting, collections

I have multiple objects in the scene which I'd like to rename in ascending order at once.

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with Batch Rename.

1. Select all objects to be renamed. Make sure the first objekt is the active one
   [image]
2. Give objects a new name starting with suffix .001
   [image]
3. Delete new name without last character and assign new name.
   [image]
4. That´s it
   [image]

By script:

```
import bpy

objs = bpy.context.selected_objects
active_int = int(bpy.context.active_object.name)

for obj in objs[1:]:   # without active one
    obj.name = str(active_int + objs.index(obj))
```